# How to locate element under <div></div> tag in selenium

Tags: java, selenium

There is a simple div tag with text. How to build xpath from the below tag.

```
 WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='el2']"));
 <DIV align=”left” id=e1>Insured</DIV> 


 Actions action = new Actions(driver);
 //To mouseover on main menu
 action.moveToElement(element).build().perform();
```

Since the id is changing every time, I need to use the text in a div tag

Comment: Can you post the full html structure of the element for which you want to get the xpath

Comment: @SameerArora : 
<DIV onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#4B0082';style.color='lightblue';this.style.cursor='default';ShM=1;; popi('show-menu=contacts','menu1',2);;;return stch('');" onmouseout="rep_img(); popdn(this,2, 'menu1', 'show-menu=contacts', 'navy', '#FFFFFF');;; return stch('');" id=el2 style="CURSOR: default; FONT-SIZE: 10px; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana, Arial; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; COLOR: #ffffff; PADDING-BOTTOM: 4px; FONT-STYLE: normal; PADDING-TOP: 4px; PADDING-LEFT: 4px; PADDING-RIGHT: 4px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: navy" align=left valign="top">Contacts</DIV>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this below Xpath if your ID keeps changing. This should work fine.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//DIV[contains(text(), 'Contacts')]"))
```

OR

```
  WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//DIV[text()[contains(.,'Contacts')]]"))
```

Comment: Getting Error for both the solutions : Unable to find element with xpath

Comment: Did you change the value of text from 'Insured' to 'Contacts'?

Comment: I have updated the value Contacts which you have posted in other message.Try Now